# Rowwidget plugin inside the rowwidget

Tags: extjs

I have some problems with the rowwidget
I have a rowwidget plugin inside the rowwidget to display nested tables.
It looks like the picture(1). But there is a problem when I expand the record of the second level.
The height of the parent row is not set correctly and the records are not visible (picture 2).

Does anyone know how to make the height of the row automatically recalculated by the size of the expand row?

picture(1)
[image]

picture(2)
[image]

My code:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
            fields: ['name', 'email', 'phone'],
            data: [{
                name: 'A',
                email: 'lisa@simpsons.com',
                phone: '555-111-1224',
                orders: [{
                    item: 'A11',
                    desc: 'Stand',
                    orde: [{
                        item: 'A111',
                        desc: 'Stand',

                    }, {
                        item: 'A222',
                        desc: 'Holder'
                    }, {
                        item: 'A333',
                        desc: 'Hanger'
                    }]

                }, {
                    item: 'A22',
                    desc: 'Holder',
                    orde: [{
                        item: 'A222',
                        desc: 'Stand',

                    }, {
                        item: 'A333',
                        desc: 'Holder'
                    }, {
                        item: 'A444',
                        desc: 'Hanger'
                    }]
                }, {
                    item: 'A33',
                    desc: 'Hanger',
                    orde: [{
                        item: 'A333',
                        desc: 'Stand',

                    }, {
                        item: 'A444',
                        desc: 'Holder'
                    }, {
                        item: 'A555',
                        desc: 'Hanger'
                    }]
                }]
            } ]
        });

        Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
            title: 'Simpsons',
            store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
            columns: [{
                text: 'Name',
                dataIndex: 'name',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Email',
                dataIndex: 'email',
                flex: 1
            }, {
                text: 'Phone',
                dataIndex: 'phone',
                flex: 1
            }],
            height: Ext.getBody().getHeight(),
            width: '100%',
            plugins: [{
                ptype: 'rowwidget',
                widget: {
                    xtype: 'grid',
                    maxHeight: 300,
                    title: false,
                    bind: {
                        store: '{record.orders}',

                    },
                    plugins: [{
                        ptype: 'rowwidget',
                        widget: {
                            xtype: 'grid',
                            maxHeight: 200,
                            title: false,
                            bind: {
                                store: '{record.orde}',
                            },
                            columns: [{
                                text: 'Item',
                                dataIndex: 'item',
                                flex: 1
                            }, {
                                text: 'Description',
                                dataIndex: 'desc',
                                flex: 2
                            }]
                        }
                    }],
                    columns: [{
                        text: 'Item',
                        dataIndex: 'item',
                        flex: 1
                    }, {
                        text: 'Description',
                        dataIndex: 'desc',
                        flex: 2
                    }]
                }
            }],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: The height of the grid is fixed: try adding `scrollable: true` in the grid definition.

Comment: @Arthur thx, but that's not what I'm looking for. In your example, the grid would have many scrolls. I would like to have one scroll per main grid.

I solved my problem with  `manageHeight: false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem with `manageHeight: false`